# What are they saying and what does it mean?

Tags: translation

Please listen to this short extract from a gintama episode:
http://picosong.com/VzF8

What exactly are they saying?
The part I don't get is specifically "ni kawareru ni" and "narete".
Do they really mean kawaru?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says 「自分はこんな素敵な主人達に飼われるにふさわしい、素敵な犬になれているだろうか？」

飼われる is the passive form of 飼う, to keep (a pet).

～にふさわしい means "to deserve"

なれて(なれる) is the potential form of なる, to become.

Comment: thanks a lot.
one more question, what form is narete? there's a te-form based on a potential form?

Comment: Yes, なれて is the te-form of なれる(can become). なれている(have been able to become) is the progressive form of なれる.